# Bash-скрипт сортировка последних файлов

Tags: bash

Задача:

Скрипт должен принимать обязательный параметр <PATH_TO_DIR>

В директории PATH_TO_DIR выбирать 3 последних файла, по дате изменения, но не старше 7 дней.

Мой скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1
last=`find $dir -type f -mtime -7`
mv $last /test
```

хочу переместить 3 последних файла в директорию /test
как мне дополнить скрипт, чтобы была сортировка по трем последним файлам в параметре path_to_dir?

Answer (score 2):

`find` отыскивает все не старые файлы в директории и печатает их время и полный путь. `sort` сортирует строки по времени. `head` отбирает три самых свежих файла. `cut` убирает время из строк:

```
#!/bin/bash
last=`find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -7 -printf "%T@\t%p\n" | sort -nr | head -3 | cut -f "2-"`
mv $last /test
```

Форматная строка в printf:

> ```
> %T@ - время обновления файла в виде вещественного числа в секундах;
> \t  - табуляция (разделитель между временем и именем файла);
> %p  - путь к файлу файла;
> \n  - перевод строки.
> ```

Больше подробностей в `man find`.

Comment: спасибо, а что в данном случае означает -printf "%T@\t%p\n" ?

Comment: Добавил в ответ.